# How to exit while input falsely with cmd environment while using mysql

Tags: mysql, cmd

I can't retrieve the control of inputting code in a new line when I input falsely in cmd environment like following pic shows:

[image: a screenshot of cmd environment]

In order to restart input all I can do at the moment is to shut cmd window down and open it again.

Comment: rather you should use 'exit' command.

Comment: @Akhter Thanks a lot but that doesn't make sense.However, I found that I have to input another ' to end the false inputting command line, then I can retrieve the control of inputting again.

Comment: You are entering a multi-line command, so this seems totally expected.

Comment: @Eiko Thanks a lot!